# Ubuntu 20.04 Wont boot

Tags: 20.04, rufus

Im trying to boot ubuntu 20.04 from a usb made with rufus 3.12 from a windows 10 computer different to the one im trying to boot ubuntu on. When I go to boot ubuntu it then does a disk check when the disk check is done with no problems i get ubuntu with the 3 spinning dots and after a few seconds the dots stop spinning and nothing else happens. Ctrl+alt+Fkey does not change to a terminal. No idea why this is happening and would like some insight

Comment: At the three spinning dots, press Esc. You may get some clue about what is going on.

Comment: Hanging after snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount

Comment: Acer Predator PH317-53, graphics card kicking out?

Comment: It is dual boot. Had some problems with windows side. Messages seen on boot to ubuntu. Disk contains unclean file system. Windows cache

Comment: Just looked up specs of your computer, webpage says Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070.

Comment: on Windows side, you'll need to do a clean shutdown and make sure the disks all check out.  On Ubuntu side... could be video card problem.  I don't know anything about Nvidia though.

Comment: Well that kinda worked. I removed my bois battery and main power battery and thats got me into ubuntu again. Can you move that to an answer so i can upvote